# Flutter Integration Testing - The non-nullable local variable 'driver' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing

I'm a flutter beginner. I'm testing my application in 'integration testing' mode. I have added the required packages. I'm getting the below error in the test code. Can anyone help me solve this?

Error:

The non-nullable local variable '**driver**' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution

Error lines:

```
FlutterDriver driver;
    Future<bool> isPresent(SerializableFinder byValueKey,
    {Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 1)}) async {
      try {
        await driver .waitFor(byValueKey, timeout: timeout);
        return true;
      } catch (exception){
        return false;
      }

tearDownAll(() async {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
      }
    });
```

app test code:

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';


void main() {

  group('Toyzania App', () {
    
    //login screen
    final emailField = find.byValueKey('Email');
    final passwordField = find.byValueKey('Password');
    final loginButton = find.byValueKey('Login');
    final CreateAccountButton = find.byValueKey('CreateAccount');
    final logoutButton = find.byValueKey('Logout');



    FlutterDriver driver;
    Future<bool> isPresent(SerializableFinder byValueKey,
    {Duration timeout = const Duration(seconds: 1)}) async {
      try {
        await driver .waitFor(byValueKey, timeout: timeout);
        return true;
      } catch (exception){
        return false;
      }
    }

    setUpAll(() async {
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    tearDownAll(() async {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
      }
    });

    test('login', () async{
      if(await isPresent(logoutButton)){
        await driver.tap(logoutButton);
      }

      await driver.tap(emailField);
      await driver.enterText('test11@gmail.com');

      await driver.tap(passwordField);
      await driver.enterText('123456');

      await driver.tap(loginButton);
      await driver.waitFor(find.text("My Account"));
    });

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check whether `driver` is `null` before you call its `waitFor` method:

```
      if (driver != null) {
        await driver .waitFor(byValueKey, timeout: timeout);
        return true;
      }
       return false;
```